# Pull from two different tables and order

Tags: mysql

```
TABLE 1
id  time1   info
1   110 info1
2   120 info2

TABLE 2
id  time2   info
1   100 info3
2   130 info4
```

How could I pull data from both tables at once and order by time1 and time2 (same thing, but the fields have different names)

```
Expected result row ids:
1 // table 2
1 // table 1
2 // table 1
2 // table 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `UNION JOIN` queries, alias the common sorting columns (time1 and time2) to have the same name and sort the entire reunited result-set.

```
(SELECT id, time1 AS time, info FROM table1)
    UNION
(SELECT id, time2 AS time, info FROM table2)
    ORDER BY time
```

Unfortunately this means not being able to return different table structures per table. They Have to match regarding number of columns and such.

A workaround would be something like this:

```
(SELECT id, time1 AS time, info, extra_column FROM table1)
    UNION
(SELECT id, time2 AS time, info, NULL AS extra_column FROM table2)
    ORDER BY time
```

Comment: One more thing. What if I needed to return one extra column from table1 for example (table2 has no such column).

Comment: Thanks a lot, figured out the "NULL AS column" part when you posted this :)