# Select/Order data from two tables

Tags: javascript, mysql, sqlite

I have two tables holding game data for two different games. For the sake of simplicity, let's say they only share a column called `Timestamp` (in particular they have a different number of columns). I want to render a list holding information from both tables, simultaneously ordered by `Timestamp`.

What I'm currently doing works, but I'd take almost any bet that there is a much better way to do this. I'm mostly concerned about performance at some point (mobile app). This is a stub representing the structure – believe me, I know how horrible this looks right now. I just wanted to make it work first, now I'm looking for improvements. ;)

```
var readyA,
    readyB = false;

var dataA, 
    dataB;

function doLoop () {
    setTimeout(renderData, 100);
}

function renderData () {
    if (!readyA || !readyB) {
        doLoop();
        return;
    }

    var dataAll = dataA.concat(dataB);
    dataAll.sort(function (a,b) {
        return a['Timestamp'] <= b['Timestamp'];
    });

    // pass data into a template depending on from which game it is and render it
    // ...
}

// wait for both queries to finish
doLoop();

// select data from game A
myDatabaseClass.query('SELECT ... FROM GameA', function (results) {
    dataA = new Array(results.rows.length);
    for (var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++) { 
        dataA[i] = results.rows.item(i); 
    }

    readyA = true;
});

// select data from game B
myDatabaseClass.query('SELECT ... FROM GameB', function (results) {
    dataB = new Array(results.rows.length);
    for (var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++) { 
        dataB[i] = results.rows.item(i); 
    }

    readyB = true;
});
```

The question would now be if I can somehow simplify this by some kind of `UNION` or `JOIN` in the query. Obviously, the `Timeout` construction is horrible, but that will automatically collapse to a simple callback function if the querying can be done in one query (or at least one transaction – the database class can handle that).

*Edit*: I did found this ( [Pull from two different tables and order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252621/pull-from-two-different-tables-and-order?rq=1) ) but this whole `NULL AS some_column` feels dirty. Is there really no better alternative?

Comment: @Fahim Parkar: This is somewhat off-topic, but what's wrong with "Thanks in advance"?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97136/suggested-edits-add-thanks-in-advance

Comment: Oh, alright. Well then – I wanted to be polite, but if it's considered clutter, I will leave it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is pretty good.  From the point of view of a SQL hacker like me you're doing the UNION and the ORDER  BY on the client side.  There's nothing wrong with that. You seem to be doing it almost right.  Your "concat" is the client-side equivalent of UNION, and your "sort' is the equivalent of ORDER BY.

You say that the `NULL as missing-column` construction feels somehow dirty if you use server-side `UNION` operations.  But, obviously to treat two different result sets as the same so you can sort them in order you have to make them conform to each other somehow.  Your `a['Timestamp'] <= b['Timestamp']` sort-ordering criterion in your sort function is also a scheme for conforming two result sets to each other. It may be lower-performance than using a UNION.

Don't be afraid of using `NULL as missing-column` to make two result sets in a UNION conform to each other. It's not dirty, and it's not expensive.

Do consider limiting your SELECT operation somehow, perhaps by a range of timestamps.  That will allow your system to scale up, especially if you put an index on the column you use to limit the SELECT.

(By the way, your sort function has a mistake in it. sort functions need to return -1, 0, or +1 depending on whether the first item is less than, equal to, or greater than the second one. You're returning a true/false value.  That doesn't work properly.)

(You're parallelizing the two queries to the same MySQL instance.  That's clever, but probably in truth is a formula for overloading MySQL as your game scales up.  Keep in mind that each user of your game has her own machine running Javascript but they all share your MySQL.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment. In this case I'm actually not worried about either hackers or users sharing MySQL because this is about SQLite running on mobile phones, so every user has their own database (and manipulating their own database .. I mean, if they want to, I won't stop them). I'm aware of the flaw in the compare function, although I can know for sure the case '0' would never happen, but I was going to make it better anyway. Limiting of the number of games is implemented in the way that the user will be asked to empty the database when a certain number of entries exist [tbc]

Comment: … as this database is actually just holding temporary games. The reason I want to get rid of the parallel queries (which generally aren't bad) is to get rid of the Timeout construction. I'm not sure how much better the performance of parallel queries is on a mobile phone anyway. Thanks for your input, I guess I'll go with the "dirty" ( ;) ) solution of conforming the schemes.

Comment: Many sorting algorithms *will* compare some item to itself.

Comment: That makes sense – didn't really think about that.

Comment: I ended up using the original approach with two queries, but instead of the timeout construction I just called `doIt` from both queries (this will be sufficient -- whichever one finishes last will make the main part of `doIt` actually be executed). I did this because the tables are not exactly small and I feel like that makes the code more maintainable, so unless there's a good argument against using two queries rather than `UNION ALL` I will stick with this for now.

Answer (score 2):

The result of a query always is a single table with a fixed number of columns, so all the `SELECT`s must have the same number of columns:

```
SELECT a1, a2, a3,   Timestamp FROM GameA
UNION ALL
SELECT b1, b2, NULL, Timestamp FROM GameB
ORDER BY Timestamp
```

(`UNION ALL` is faster than `UNION` because it doesn't try to remove duplicates.)

Comment: Thanks. Does the type of the column matter? Both tables have quite a few columns. Some columns are actually the same, but most aren't. Also, in SQLite, can I later easily detect from which table a row came? In another thread I read about also selecting something like `"GameA" AS Type`, but this didn't seem to work in SQLite.

Comment: Oh, and the tip with `UNION ALL` being faster than `UNION` is helpful too. Thanks!

Comment: Due to SQLite's dynamic typing, column types do not matter for this. In SQL, strings use single quotes.

Comment: Thank you, I will try again with single quotes!